# ssh site as parameter of jenkins job

Tags: ssh, jenkins

I use jenkins to connect towards a ssh site and do some operation. This is possible through Publish Over SSH Plugin and it works well, but I have a lot of server and to use a ssh site I need to configure each one. I would like to use the ip of my machine as parameter in a jenkins job, without any configuration.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would probably answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26481496/4850949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem whatsoever to put the IP address of your machine as, say, a string parameter for your build. You may put your machine's host name as well. I suppose though that I am missing something in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Probaby it's because my bad english. Currently i'm able to use any machine (with ip and hostname as well). My problem is that I need to configure each one in "configure jenkins", but I'd like to use it without configure anything just as job parameter. In this way I can use any my machine without further configuration.

Comment: You mean you want to run a job on a slave without configuring the slave first?

Comment: No, I want to send ssh command (like publish my build on a server) without configuring (or creating) it in "configure jenkins" and after setting it in my job. I want to give the address at job launching through a parameter.