# How to Control Parametrized publishing in Jenkins using Publish over SSH plugin's Label field

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins  ["Publish over Ssh"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) plugin how do I use the Label(Advanced options) aka  Parameterized publishing feature. How do I use the label field.  What do I put in  the Label field. Do I need to put a variable name(one I can read from build param) that would have the Machine Name . I tried out the same 
Here is what I did:

I had a machine name QA_1 and I had one variable jenkins build $MC_NAME pointed to XXX . I entered $MC_NAME in the LABEL field. but to my surprise Jenkins was publishing to QA_1 machine irrespective of what the value of $MC_NAME variable.

**Can some one PLease tell me  the exact steps to control which machine to publish/run scripts by using  LABEL filed in "Publish over Ssh" plugin in Jenkins**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should enable "parameterized publishing" and specify build parameter name by clicking "Advanced..." button that is last before "Add post-build action" button in your build config (I use post-build actions section for example).

E.g. "build parameter name" = `SSH_SERVER`. Then there should be `SSH_SERVER` build parameter with regexp to match ssh servers labels.

In your case, `SSH_SERVER` build parameter should be set to XXX, after that SSH publishing should happen only for QA_1 server.

Comment: Ah, Just missed the Advanced button that is present below Add Transfer Set button,  Thanks a lot dude for the help

Comment: This also applies to publish over FTP (and probably any other plugins in the publish over... family"). It took me a while to figure out why publish over FTP was ignoring my labels. Docs: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over#PublishOver-Parametername

Answer (score 17):

Answer to your question and how I configured my process:

### 1. Configuring Jenkins

1. Install Publish over SSH plugin
2. Configure Jenkins => System Configuration
3. Publish over SSH section

   - Key => -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ... here is your key ... -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
     1.2.1.2 SSH Servers =>
   - Name: Server_1 (It is only name of configuration)
   - Hostname: example_server_1.com (url of your server)
   - Username: ec2-user (for amazon)
   - Click *Add Server* button
   - Name: Server_2 (It is only name of configuration)
   - Hostname: example_server_2.com (url of your server)
   - Username: ec2-user (for amazon)

### 2. Job Configuration

1. Open Job => Configure
2. Check *This project is parameterized*
3. Add Choice Parameter

   - Name: server
   - Choices:

     ```
      server_1
      server_2
     ```
4. Select *Send files or execute commands over SSH* => SSH Server section

   - Name: select your first server
   - Enter Transfer Set data (Source files and/or Exec_command)
   - Click *Advanced*
   - Label: server_1 (this is the first choice of your choice parameter)
   - Click *Add Server*
   - Name: select your second server
   - Enter Transfer Set data (Source files and/or Exec_command)
   - Click *Advanced*
   - Label: server_2 (this is the second choice of your choice parameter)
   - In front of button *Add Server*, click *Advanced*
   - Check *Parameterized publishing*
   - Parameter name: server (this is the name of your choice parameter)

### 3. Job Running

Run job and select for example Server => server_2.

You will see in log:

```
SSH: Skipping [server_1] - Label server_1 does not match expression server_2
SSH: Publishing to [server_2] - Label server_2 matches expression server_2
SSH: Connecting from host [ip-10-0-0-37]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [server_2] ...
```

### Explanation

The plugin compares the value of the parameter named "Server" (which you selected before job starts) with the labels that you have configured. If label and parameter match, then the SSH commands are executed.

Hope it was helpful. Cause I spent on it 5 hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear friend. You explained it so beautifully. Worked like a charm.