# Jenkins ssh on server ip passed as build parameter

Tags: ssh, jenkins

my question is simple - Is there a Jenkins ssh plugin with which I can accomplish parameterized build with different server ips. I've tried "Publish over ssh", but the server ips are registered in jenkins configuration page and I couldn't find a way to add them as build parameter.

Comment: How are you planning on getting the correct value into the parameter?  Is it coming from an environment variable, or the result of another build, or is it user-entered at build time, or...?

Comment: It is user-entered at build time.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/53608875/pos-default.png?version=1&modificationDate=1321575097000 I want to use parameter like ${TARGET_SERVER_IP} instead this combobox with predefined servers.

Comment: you can add "${TARGET_SERVER_IP}" string to server address field in SSH sites. it will warn you, that it cannot connect to server, just go on. then, add a build parameter TARGET_SERVER_IP, and in combobox of the step choose your "user@${TARGET_SERVER_IP}:22" site

Comment: @daniel.bavrin have you tried that? It doesn't work.

Comment: @kai, yes, i did have tried that, and it works. But notice the important moment: the step (**Execute shell script on remote host using ssh**), where you use the variable, must be one of "build" steps, not "build environment" checkbox with the same name.

Comment: @daniel.bavrin: right, the OP was using "Publish over SSH". I guess you're using "SSH plugin" instead. Anyway, with the latter plugin, I managed to use a variable to specify the IP field, but I'd like to do the same for the ssh username and it results in an auth error. Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Control Parametrized publishing in Jenkins using Publish over SSH plugin's Label field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411489/how-to-control-parametrized-publishing-in-jenkins-using-publish-over-ssh-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add all of the possible servers as SSH servers, assign each a label (could be ip) & set up transfer set/exec commands for every one, even if they are all identical.

Add a string parameter to your build for the server name, ie. SERVERS.

Then you turn on  "parameterized publishing" under the Advanced section at the bottom of all the servers in the build configuration. You give it the name of the parameter you added above (SERVERS) that will hold a regex that is compared to all of the labels.

The regex is based on Java - so .* matches all the labels. A string with the full ip address would just match the one server with that ip as the label.

It's a bit clunky, but it does work.

Comment: Should the variable be prefixed with a '$' or is it raw? ie- `$SERVERS` or `SERVERS`. I'm about to try this and find out for myself, but this would be useful for others who come here later. Also, do you have a link to documentation for this?

Comment: How do we assign a label to each SSH server? I couldn't see that in the SSH Servers section in Global Configuration page.

Comment: @JamesSelvakumar: You do that in the build config itself, for each server you add to it. There should be a "Label" checkbox. It is in the Advanced section just below where you select the name of the server. When you check the Label-checkbox, a text field appears where you set the label.

Answer (score 0):

Several options here:

1. You want to run several builds, each one with a different IP address, and the IP addresses don't change.  Use a [Matrix build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) with a user-defined axis.
2. You want to run one build, but each time you run it, you want to manually enter a new IP address.  Use the [build with parameters](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+With+Parameters+Plugin) plugin.
3. You want to run one build, and the IP address to use can you derived from another build.  Use the [parameterized build trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) plugin.

There's probably a few more options, so if I haven't got your scenario quite right, just amend your question a bit and I'll amend this answer acccordingly.