# Jenkins SSH plugin: Parameterizing remote host

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, I am using SSH Plugin to run shell commands on a remote machine via ssh. I have added my SSH sites to global configuration.
But under "Execute shell script on remote host using ssh" section of my Jobs configuration, instead of just selecting one of the SSH sites from the drop down, I would like to consume a build parameter. This way I would like to generalize this job to remote to different environments depending on my requirements.

Is there a way to parameterize ssh site drop down? Or achieve my requirement in a different way?

BTW one option I already have is, to have ssh to remote machine as part of the script and execute it there.

Comment: have you tried parametrized build. Probably this could help you: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: no Priyanshu. This probably wont work in my case as I don't know how to consume this parameter in the pre-configured drop down (through global configuration) for SSH sites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Control Parametrized publishing in Jenkins using Publish over SSH plugin's Label field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411489/how-to-control-parametrized-publishing-in-jenkins-using-publish-over-ssh-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to parameterize the SSH server. Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26481496/361172) for details.

Answer (score 1):

There are two plugin's available to help you.
Assuming you have limited ssh connections following may help you.

1) [MultiJob](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) Plugin:- You can create downstream Jobs which will take input from previous builds.So based on your parameters you can configure new jobs for different SSH connections. For eg:-

if you have 4 ssh connections A,B,C,D
make 4 sub jobs for each connection. you can write simple if else conditions which Job to select if input parameter is A,B,C,D.

2) [JobDSL](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) Plugin:- Similar way you need to schedule your build jobs based on input from previous i.e you need to write some groovy if else conditions to select which connection you want to use if input parameter is A,B,C,D.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Above mentioned is good approach but it is not answering the question. I think question is, Can we pass target server name as a variable to plugin at job level, rather than defining in global configurations. Advise if it can be achieved by any of above approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Defenately possible with [Publish Over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) plugin.

You can also refer the link [here](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-parameterized-publishing/) for detailed steps.